# SecByteBlock won't accept string as custom key

Tags: c++, aes, crypto++

I am trying to use a custom key with Crypto++. My program works with a random key, but I am getting a intellisense error when I try to pass `SecByteBlock` a key.

The reference [here](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_sec_block.html)  defines it as `SecBlock (const T *t, size_type len)` but I have never encountered const T before.

```
void EncryptFile(string cEncryptionKey, string cFilePath, string cTempFilepath)
    SecByteBlock key_aes(pEncryptionKey, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);//giving error
    //SecByteBlock key_aes(ES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH); // Generates a random key
```

Comment: Intellisense is not the compiler. Does the compiler give you an error?

Answer (score 2):

A `SecByteBlock` is a typedef for [`SecBlock< T, A >`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_sec_block.html) with `T = byte`. The three constructors are:

```
SecBlock (size_type size=0)
SecBlock (const SecBlock< T, A > &t)
SecBlock (const T *t, size_type len)
```

There is no constructor which you are trying to use. This does not exist:

```
SecByteBlock (const string& str, size_type size)
```

So you only need to:

```
ASSERT(key.size() == AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
SecByteBlock key_aes(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(key.data()), key.size());
```

You may need to perform a `static_cast<size_t>(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH)`, but you usually do not have to. If you use `-Wextra`, `-Wsign-conversion` or `-Wconversion`, you may have to.

---

Stepping back to 10,000 feet, you should probably avoid putting the key in a `string` to begin with.

Create a `SecByteBlock` with a size (the first constructor above), and read directly into it. Then, pass the `SecByteBlock` by reference to `EncryptFile`.

---

Related, we are just about at the point we get a clean compile with `-Wall`, so you should probably enable it in your project. To use the cleaner sources, you need to [checkout from SVN](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SVN) or [clone from Git](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/GitHub_and_Git).